# Bitbucket repository push changes to deploy on Media Temple Grid server development site

Tags: git, bitbucket, mediatemple

Despite searching far and wide, I've not come up with a clear solution to this, and Media Temple balked at helping out with any git related issues.

I simply want to push commits to my bitbucket repository, then push those changes to my production site at Media Temple.  It's on shared hosting grid server.  I have no issues pushing commits to my bitbucket repository but pushing them to production site is where I'm getting hung up.

Any nice tutorials or suggestions for this?  Sorry for the general question.